# Spring @Async Executor

Tags: java, spring

Is there anyway to be able to specify different Executors for different classes? Seems a bit constricting to have to use one Executor for every async task.

Comment: You can have the pooled executor with enough threads.

Answer (score 3):

As of Spring 3.2/3.1.2 you can now qualify your `@Async` use, much like the use of `@Transactional`, in the following manner:

```
@Async("beanNameOrQualifierValue")
public void someOp() {
   ...
}
```

You can look in the following issues [SPR-6847](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6847) (3.2) / [SPR-9443](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-9443) (3.1.2) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can have several instances of the same task executor type (Pool). But you can not have different Pools.

For example

```
  <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10"/>
```

10 instances of `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`

or

```
   <task:executor id="executorWithPoolSizeRange"
               pool-size="5-25"
               queue-capacity="100"/>
```

For more details see the spring Reference
@see [Spring Reference Chapter 25 Task Execution and Scheduling](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html)